# Azure Repository Plugin access denied to elasticsearch.keystore

Tags: elasticsearch

I've installed Azure Repository plugin into my 6.4 ES instance on my Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS box which is hosted inside of a VM in Azure. I'm trying to perform backups and restores using a storage account I created in azure. When I try to set the account and key values I get the following error from the console:
"Exception in thread 'main' java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore".
I've tried running on sudo and still the same error.

Details of the issue can be found in the link below:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/azure-repository-plugin-access-denied-to-elasticsearch-keystore/149904

Answer (score 0):

I'd resolved my issue by updating the following permissions on the elasticsearch.keystore file:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore - All Users
sudo chmod u+rwx /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore - Group
sudo chmod g+rwx /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore - Owner
```